# How to provide specific port in Bluemix?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

I'm using bluemix with python buildpack. In the code example, port always provided programmatically. like this,

```
port = os.getenv('PORT', '5000')
```

but my app using webpy and the way webpy serve application is `python welcome.py 5000`. that will serve http on port 5000. 
How to achieve that with cloud foundry on bluemix? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with adding this `web: python welcome.py $PORT` in Procfile.